# How to get the build base from setup.py file

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to get what is the build base (because the default can be overridden by -b or --build-base option) from within the distribution setup.py file, other than parsing the arguments.

Comment: It happens to be a subdirectory named "build" in the project directory. But this can be overridden in the setup.cfg file as well as the CLI. The default is just documented, not sure if you can get it from the script.